# Manipulating table update for php using SQLDeveloper instead of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

I have created a table in SQLDeveloper, populated it with user data (Username, email, password, password) in PHP and am able to delete user data as well. Now what I want to do is modify data in table. The only syntax I can find online is that for MySQL and I'm trying to fix it so it can work in SQLDeveloper. This is the code I'm using that's set up for MySQL.

My Table is called MANCITY and the only thing I wish to update is the customer username. I've left it in MySQL form rather than have a mix of some things I think may be right fo SQLDeveloper and get myself mixed with the two. Thanks!

```
<?php

$dbuser = "s";
$dbpassword = "t";
$db = "o";

$con=mysqli_connect("$dbuser,$dbpassword,$db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE MANCITY SET USERNAME=JOHN
WHERE USERNAME='JON' AND EMAIL='JRYE@GMAIL.COM'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Edit**:

My main issue is how to change it so it can connect to my Oracle database.

Comment: Sidenote: You're missing the host parameter for your DB credentials. General syntax is `$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);` no quotes.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't put across my problem well. You see, that's code for MySQL I'm sure I can't use "mysqli();" when I'm trying to get it to connect to my SQLDeveloper database. My main issue is how to change it so it can connect to my Oracle database.

Comment: I edited your question with your comment as well as adding the relevant "Oracle" tag. In the future, *please* add all relevant information, so that people (*including myself*) won't be misled and give incorrect answers, as I did; which I ended up deleting my answer. @user3457441 *Welcome to StackOverflow* ;-)

Comment: This is an Oracle DB connection example `$con=oci_connect("system","123","localhost/orcl");` the rest of the queries resemble themselves a lot. Have you Google'd Oracle SQL?

Comment: Sorry, I thought "using SQLDeveloper instead of MySQL" was clear enough. I haven't google "oracle" instead I've been looking for SQLDeveloper specifically because I wasn't sure if Oracle was too vague.

Comment: Not a problem. StackOverflow has many tags available and `Oracle` is one that has over `4.1k` followers. You'll be sure to get a better response using the proper relevant tags (*in the future*).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle <= click on that and you will see many questions (*and possible answers*) on StackOverflow related to Oracle. That's basically how I get answers at times, and where I learned SQL; that and Google (*and practice*). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You may either use [PDO with the Oracle driver](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-oci.php), which has the advantage that you can practically read any PDO-PHP tutorial and most likely will only need to change the line which constructs the PDO object. This extension is still marked as `experimental` though.

Another variant is to use the [direct Oracle extension](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.oci8.php), which will only work with Oracle and no other DBMS. While this may offer you more oracle native features, you will find a lot less information following this way.

With the PDO extension the following should work:

```
<?php
$db_username = "youusername";
$db_password = "yourpassword";
$db = "oci:dbname=yoursid";

$conn = new PDO($db,$db_username,$db_password);
// Another way to connect which might work
// $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/mydb', $db_username, $db_password);

$st = $conn->prepare('UPDATE MANCITY SET USERNAME=? WHERE USERNAME=? AND EMAIL=?');
$st->execute(array("JOHN", "JON", "JRYE@GMAIL.COM"));
```